# cmake in docker failed to init submodules

Tags: windows, git, docker, cmake, mingw

Im building image from Dockerfile and anytime i try to mingw32-make some cmake project with `ExternalProject_Add` and `GIT_REPOSITORY` url - it fails with

```
CMake Error at C:/cura-build/build/Uranium-prefix/tmp/Uranium-gitclone.cmake:84 (message):
  Failed to init submodules in:
  'C:/cura-build/build/Uranium-prefix/src/Uranium'
```

the command to init submodules which is refered in error log is generated by cmake and looks like this:

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND "C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe" ${git_options} submodule init
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "C:/cura-build/build/CuraEngine-prefix/src/CuraEngine"
  RESULT_VARIABLE error_code
  )
if(error_code)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to init submodules in: 'C:/cura-build/build/CuraEngine-prefix/src/CuraEngine'")
endif()
```

some info:
docker is latest stable 18.06.1-ce-win73 (19507)
image is FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016
i can successfully clone Uranium and exec `git submodule init` without errors from container in interactive mode

full log: [here](https://gist.github.com/lamest/55d124eb615de48485abf1adbadf1cce)

[Uranium-gitclone.cmake](https://gist.github.com/lamest/1f0eb8026f2901682e337b115e6dd334)

Comment: Before the line `message(FATAL_ERROR)` add a line `message("Command: \"C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe\" ${git_options} submodule init"`) and rerun building process. It will show you exact command line which is failed, so you may try to run it by yourself.

Comment: i sort of know exact line becase i can read full Uranium-gitclone.cmake. it can add `-c http.sslVerify=false`. but with cmake it wont work and it works from command line no matter with or without sslVerify